# How to validate a lognormal random walk for time series data

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, validation

I am currently working on a project where I need to simulate the prices of a set of $D$ substitutable commodities over time.

I was hoping to do this using the following $D$-dimensional lognormal random walk model:

$$\ln(p_{t}) = \ln(p_{t-1}) + \varepsilon_t, $$

where $p_{t}$ is a $D\times 1$ vector containing the prices of all commodities at time $t$, and $\varepsilon_t$ is a $D$-dimensional Gaussian random variable with mean $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^D$ and covariance $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times D}$.

Given $T$ data points on the prices, $(p_{t})_{t=1}^T$, I can fit this model by constructing [MLE estimates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) for the parameters, $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\Sigma}$.

My question is: what is the right way to `validate" my model in such a case? Is there an interpretable`metric" to assess the predictive capacity of the random walk?

Comment: wouldn't the size of the changes $\varepsilon$ tend to be proportional to the price (e.g. if price is \$100, it might shift by say \$5, but if price is \$1, surely it's not going to be doing that)? Also, if price is low, it can't decrease by more than the current price ($p$ can't go negative) but it *can* increase by more than the current price. That is, to be realistic $\varepsilon$ would seem to need to be (i) multiplicative, not additive and (ii) right skewed. (In particular, wouldn't it be more common to model log-price as a random walk?)

Comment: You don't need MCMC. Closed form MLE estimates are readily available.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes that's absolutely correct. I changed the question to reflect this. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @Taylor Thank you for pointing this out! I changed the question around to use the MLE estimates instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of $p_t-p_{t-k}$ can be compared with the one your model predicted.

Comment: Thanks for this. Two questions: 1. What is the right way to choose $k$ in this case? 2. Is there a metric to compare the distributions (i.e. do you use KL-divergence or something?)

Comment: Thats how I would attack the problem. I don't know about the details.